# Assign a output of jps -vl command to a variable in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sh

I need to assign the output of a command to a variable. The command I tried is:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 JAVA_PROCESSES=`jps -vl | grep -v 'sun.tools.jps.Jps' | grep -v 'hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main' | grep -v grep`
 NUMBER_OF_JAVA_PROCESSES=`echo $JAVA_PROCESSES | wc -l`
 echo $NUMBER_OF_JAVA_PROCESSES
 echo $JAVA_PROCESSES
 ..
```

When I tried as in above, all java processes grepped are assigned to JAVA_PROCESSES variable in one line. Processes are not separated by new line. Therefore $NUMBER_OF_JAVA_PROCESSES always give 1 for me.

Also $NUMBER_OF_JAVA_PROCESSES show 1 even no processes are assigned to JAVA_PROCESSES due to the empty line in $JAVA_PROCESSES.

Please suggest a way to assign grepped processes separated by new line.

Comment: What are you really trying to do in the end?  You might want to use a `while read line...` loop if you really need things line-by-line, but ultimately there might be a better way to  do what you're trying to accomplish in the end.  Also, consider using `printf '%s' "$JAVA_PROCESES"` instead of echo as it'll handle a lot of situations (including this one) better

Comment: I use `if [ $NUMBER_OF_JAVA_PROCESSES -gt 0 ]` and continue the script. Since `jps -vl | grep ..` command is used in many places I want to assign it to a variable and reused it. If I use `number_of_java_processes=$(jps -vl | grep -v .... | wc -l)`  and get the number of processes then it work fine.

Comment: Do you ever use `$JAVA_PROCESSES` for anything later, or do you only care whether  or not you found any?

Comment: Yes, I use it to print processes inside the if condition.

Comment: @Ricky ok, good question, good perspective, but why don't you combine together in one variable like _NUMBER_OF_JAVA_PROCESSES=`jps -vl | ... | wc -l`_ and then, echo this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the main thing you want is to know whether or not you got any at all, you could just test if the variable is empty:

```
java_procs=$(jps -vl | grep -v 'sun.tools.jps.Jps' | grep -v 'hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main' | grep -v grep)
if [ -z "$java_procs" ]; then
    echo "No processes"
fi
```

Also, we can simplify the `grep` by using extended regex and just needing a single processes:

```
java_procs=$(jps -vl | grep -Ev 'sun.tools.jps.Jps|hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main|grep')
```

Assuming none of the lines output by `jps` can contain linebreaks themselves, we could get the count after that if we need it:

```
num_procs=$(printf '%s\n' "$java_procs" | wc -l)
```

The main problem you were running into is that you weren't quoting your variable, so `echo $JAVA_PROCESSES` was being expanded and then subject to word splitting, so your newlines were being "eaten" by the shell.  You'd always have only one line which would be a space separated list of all the words in your `JAVA_PROCESSES` variable.  To protect from word splitting you can quote the variable, as I did in my code above.

`echo` will also always add a line break at the end, which is good sometimes, and not so good sometimes, but you should be aware of it happening (that's why you would always get a count of 1 even when there were no processes).

Comment: Thank you very much Eric. I completed my code as you suggested. It worked fine. Rather than using `echo $java_procs`  , `printf '%s\n' "$java_procs" ` always separate processes by new line.